# How to map a wildcard domain to a Windows Azure Website instance?

Tags: windows, azure

When creating a "web app" it is common to use a wildcard domain and have each client or instance of the web app on its own sub domain. Windows Azure does this themselves, for example "yourwebsite.windowsazure.net". For some unknown reason, wildcard subdomain support seems to not be there for Windows Azure Websites. I'm very frustrated with this fact, so much so as to abandon Windows Azure all together.

Is there a work around to not having to manually enter every domain name individually that you want authorized? Is there an API for this? I have a particularly hairy requirement in that I have over 100,000 sub domains I would need to do this for before I could even consider moving to Azure.

Please look deeply into this issue if you attempt to answer it as I have already and saw no other option other than manually entering through the portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you're right, and that Windows Azure Web Sites don't support this. You could, however, use a Cloud Service with a web role.

Comment: thanks. I'm one who's against learning strange paradigms outside of the core competency of web programming standards which Microsoft loves to do (web forms) etc. If you could enlighten me more on this approach and solution, I would nod you on that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'strange paradigms'.  Just load the wildcard cert on a web role, configure your DNS appropriately for CNAME wildcard mapping and your website will resolve all hostnames for a site correctly.  This has nothing to do with Windows even.  Once the domain resolves, your serverside code can extract the hostname portion and decide what to do with it (route it, authorize it, 404 it, etc.).  That is exactly how it is handled everywhere on the web.  The one and only trick to this is that your DNS provider must support wildcard CNAME mapping (e.g. no Godaddy.com support).

Comment: I should also note that if you are not using a wildcard cert - it's even easier.  Just update your DNS provider to resolve wildcard mappings on CNAMEs.  Once your XXXX.yourdomain.net resolves to <cloudservice>.cloudapp.net correctly in DNS, it is pretty trivial to route or handle the hostname portion.

Comment: @dunnry so you have verified that Windows Azure Websites can use a "Web Role" in this way? I'm seeing within the portal on "Websites" not VMs having to authorize each domain or subdomain. The CNAME and A Record stuff is trivial. I got way passed that a long time ago. Please write a blog post on this and I'm sure a lot of people will flock to it. You could even answer the question and get marks on it as a novel concept.

Comment: I actually only meant to support Steve's point.  However, if you use WAWS in reserved, you get your own IP address and hence full CNAME mapping support.  At that point, nothing prevents you from doing exactly like you do today with full WebRole.  I have done this CNAME mapping myself using PaaS webroles with hundreds of wildcard CNAME mappings.  I am 99% confident that WAWS in reserved mode will support the exact same thing given it has its own IP address and CNAME mapping.  Shared likely does as well (just not free mode).  It does not address wildcard SSL support, that not supported yet.

Comment: this was the answer as I asked some people at Microsoft directly and they told me the same.